# Advanced search / save as filter

Tags: search, filter

We have an advanced search in our app (~15 fields) and an option to save current search settings as a filter. Those filters can be selected from the dropdown and applied to current view - the advanced search fields values are set accordingly.

The question is, if somebody picks the filter and then change some fields in advanced search, should the filter "disappear" (info about chosen filter)? We wonder if there should be a possibility to edit the filter - in that case, the filter info should remain with the annotation that it's being modified and the possibility to save changes. I wonder if this is a good approach. Maybe just removing the filter and saving as new without edit option should do the trick?

Comment: How often do people change a search that they've saved? How long do they tend to keep a saved search?

Comment: Can you add mockups/wireframes?

Answer (score 3):

User is not editing the filter, if he is changing the advanced settings/parameters while the filter is applied. Editing the filter is a '**intent**' and I would suggest that instead of the system doing anything on its own, it's better to provide the user the following options at the stage/screen/place where he/she is about to re-run the search.

- Save changes to your filter "*nameofexistingfilter*".
- Create new filter with these settings   ____input the *nameofnewfilter___*

**Scenarios -**

1) I have a saved filter, but want to tweak few parameters '***temporarily***' to explore results. In this case, there is a strong chance that I do not want to override my original filter, but still want the control to edit it. I will simply ignore the above two options, and hit "Search".

2) I use an existing filter, but want to save a version with few important parameters tweaked. I will use the filter to start with, as it would help me save time with not needing to set all the other parameters again (since you mentioned ~15 fields). In this case, the edit is again necessary, but with an option to save another version. I will run the search and then come back to save the filter with new name.

3) I want to edit and make changes to the same filter. I will use the first option, of saving the same filter.

Answer (score 1):

I've answered this in another question, but I can't find it.

One method we implemented after a few workshops, was to have searches automatically saved to a list of 25, with the oldest search dropping off when a new search is carried out. The user could click a star next to the search, which would prevent it dropping off the list and it would persist.

The tab to access these searches was fixed to the bottom of the screen, which users could access from anywhere.

Not all of these features would be useful to you, but hopefully it should give you some ideas to expand on.

Answer (score 0):

As you suggest, if you provide an annotation that the search is being modified, and add options `Save` and `Save as...`, that would reflect the behavior of many productivity apps, which would be relevant if this is a productivity type setting. Perhaps the annotation does not need to be anything more than an asterisk. That would mimic e.g. how most notepads imply that the current document is edited.

<sup>(Standard conditions apply - I don't know your users or business objective, I haven't seen or tested the interface)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I like the thought of the filter being annotated to say it was modified. Depends on how important the filters are? Is the filtering really fine grained? Removing something might confuse the user. Always give feedback. I'd like to see a mock up of this.